# How to hide a form field and still have it submit all the fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I've got this rails form partial:

```
<%= form_for @ptab, :remote => true, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field', :placeholder => 'Enter a name...' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :address, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :address, :class => 'text_field', :placeholder => 'Paste a link...' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :sequence, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.number_field :sequence, :class => 'number_field', :placeholder => 'Enter an order number...' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :gtab_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.number_field :gtab_id, :class => 'number_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>


    <div class="modal-footer">
                <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
                <!-- <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")), ptabs_path, :class => 'btn' %> --> <!-- this was the original cancel button -->
                <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" href="#">Close</a>
     </div>

<% end %>
```

I would like to turn the field in the last .control-group into a hidden field, but I still want it to be submitted to the controller.

What should I change this to :

```
<div class="control-group">
        <%= f.label :gtab_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
        <div class="controls">
          <%= f.number_field :gtab_id, :class => 'number_field' %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

In order for it to not show in the rendered form but still be submitted with the form?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `hidden_field` ? Or did I miss something ?

```
<%= f.hidden_field :gtab_id %>
```

And of course remove the divs around it as well as the `label`. hidden_field are submitted as regular fields, no worries